# Vertically aligning li items in div

Tags: html, css

I have list items that displayed inline. 
I want to align  them vertically inside the green div.

```
<div id="topMenu" class="topMenu">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Documents</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

.topMenu li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.topMenu a
{
    color: White;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.topMenu
{
    background-position: center;
    background-color: Green;

    height: 30px;
    font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;

}
```

online [demo](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0F&raw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add `line-height:30px;` to your `li` elements, (*the same as the height of the menu bar*)

**[Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/d5jTf/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can just the display of your `<li>` elements a bit, like this:

```
.topMenu li
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 6px 10px;
}
```

[Check out an updated demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/cLdEW/3/)

Alternatively, you could add the padding to the `<ul>` with a new rule:

```
.topMenu ul {
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

[Check out that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/cLdEW/4/)

In either case you may want to remove the `height` from `.topMenu` and let the top/bottom padding determine it, so when the page scales with zoom on older browsers it still looks "right".
​

Comment: is there a more general way without hardcoding the padding?

Comment: I guess I need the height because i will use background image in that div so i need specific height.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go with the padding property if you want to be strict xhtml and delete vertical-align.

Furthermore it makes no sense to try to align something vertically, that is displayed inline.

Just consider: padding is the inner space between the element and the boxmodel border.

Comment: what do you mean no sense? I want items to appear in the center of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer didn't support inline-block until version 8.

You might try the work-around [here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html).

Comment: display: inline; is not supported by IE 7?

Comment: @ilann I believe IE7 supports inline but not inline-block. Here's one source http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html. And another http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=192848

Comment: @ilann please see the answer from Nick Craver, which suggests using inline-block.